# Ag-grid : Cell Editors Aginit get called twice

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

[image]Framework : Angular6+ and Ag Grid Api

I have `CellEditorcomponent` which implement `AgEditorComponent`  and upon key press, I am starting edit with agApi.startEditingCells(params) and Aginit() is executed for CellEditorComponent

this `CellEditingStartedEvent` is listen and a server call is made and based on response allow Editing. in order to make sure that user does not focus out from cell, I have re-called that `agApi.startEditingCells(params)` for same "Column and rowIndex with charpress, keyPress" but CellEditorComponent get destroyed and re-created again. 
I have following :
1) How I can prevent `agGridApi.StartEditingCell()` from calling AgInit() of CellEditor twice. 
2) is calling StartEditingCell() from same col and row index will re-created cellEditorcomponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are calling `startEditingCells` from your CellEditorComponent.
You shouldn't do that, because if your CellEditorComponent is active, then you are already editing. Calling `startEditingCells` is probably causing the grid to destroy your CellEditorComponent and create a new one, hence the multiple invocations of `agInit`

`startEditingCells` is meant for manually triggering editing from outside of the grid (usually from the grid's parent component).

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, nope I am not doing startEditingCells inside CellEditorComponent. this is happening in Parent Component